# ExtJS Charts - Turning columns on and off

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.1

Im a little bit confused with ExtJS Charts.

I have created a Column Chart thats data looks like this

```
[
    {'name':'Stu', 'score':10},
    {'name':'Jack', 'score':50},
    {'name':'Lily', 'score':100}
]
```

I have it working in the Chart, but I want to be able to turn each column off. I can display the legend but it takes all the data as one data set (which makes sense I guess).

How can I make each column be in the legend as a seperate item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to to do this in simple bar or column chart

the way to go is Group chart

here i am giving  you a sample code, run and see for yourself,hope it helps

```
     Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.define('testModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'label', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'Tom',   type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Bob',   type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Steve', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Eric',  type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Ed',    type: 'int'},
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'testModel',
    data: [{
        'label':'Friends',
        'Tom':   '5',
        'Bob':   '7',
        'Steve': '8',
        'Eric':  '9',
        'Ed':    '8'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    height: 400,
    width: 500,
    frame: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        height: 400,
        width: 500,
        xtype: 'chart',
        store: store,
        legend: {
            position: 'right'
        },
        axes: [{
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'left',
            fields: 'label',
            title: 'Friends'
        }, {
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['Tom', 'Bob', 'Steve', 'Eric', 'Ed'],
            title: 'Hours of Sleep',
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0
        }],
        series: [{
            showInLegend: true,
            type: 'bar',
            axis: 'bottom',
            xField: 'label',
            yField: ['Tom', 'Bob', 'Steve', 'Eric', 'Ed'],
        }]
    }]
});
    });
```